# Adding the result of a function in a Dataframe column [Spark Scala]

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, calculation

I want to do some calculations and add that to an existing dataframe.
I have the following function to calculate the address space based on the longitude and lattitude.

```
def getH3Address(x: Double, y: Double): String ={
    h3.get.geoToH3Address(x,y)
  }
```

I created a Dataframe with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- lat: double (nullable = true)
 |-- lon: double (nullable = true)
 |-- elevation: integer (nullable = true)
```

I want to add/append a new column to this Dataframe called `H3Address`, where the address space is calculated based on the input of the `lat` and `lon` of that row.

Here a short part of the dataframe I want to achieve:

```
+----+------------------+---------+---------+
| lat|               lon|elevation|H3Address|
+----+------------------+---------+---------+
|51.0|               3.0|       13|   a3af83|
|51.0| 3.000277777777778|       13|   a3zf83|
|51.0|3.0005555555555556|       12|   a1qf82|
|51.0|3.0008333333333335|       12|   l3xf83|
```

I tried something like:

```
df.withColumn("H3Address", geoToH3Address(df.select(df("lat")), df.select(df("lon")))
```

But this didn't work.

Can someone help me out?

**Edit:**

After adding the suggestion of @Garib, I got the following lines:

```
val getH3Address = udf(
      (lat: Double, lon: Double, res: Int) => {
        h3.get.geoToH3Address(lat,lon,res).toString
      })
    var res : Int = 10

    val DF_edit = df.withColumn("H3Address", 
 getH3Address(col("lat"), col("lon"), 10))
```

This thime, I get the error:

```
[error]  type mismatch;
  found   : Int
  required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

How can I solve this error? Tried a lot of things. For example by using `lit()` function

**Edit2**:

After using the correct way of lit(), the solution proposed has worked.

Solution:
`df.withColumn("H3Address",  getH3Address(col("lat"), col("lon"), lit(10)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a `UDF` out of your function.

> User-Defined Functions (UDFs) are user-programmable routines that act on one row

For example:

```
val getH3Address = udf(
  // write here the logic of your function. I used a dummy logic (x+y) just for this example.
  (x: Double, y: Double) => {
    (x + y).toString
  })

val df = Seq((1, 2, "aa"), (2, 3, "bb"), (3, 4, "cc")).toDF("lat", "lon", "value")
df.withColumn("H3Address", getH3Address(col("lat"), col("lon"))).show()
```

You can read more about UDFs here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-scalar.html

Comment: I stated the function I want to use already above in the text. Must I convert that def getH3Address into a UDF?

Comment: Yes, you should do it. Replace the definition of the udf from my answer to yours implementation.

Comment: now, I get a type mismatch error. See my edit above

Comment: `df.withColumn("H3Address",  getH3Address(col("lat"), col("lon"), lit(10)))` should work here. What is the error that you got when using `lit`?

Comment: don't forget to import `lit` first